# How to override spring security messages?

Tags: java, spring-security

How can I override spring messages like 'Bad Credentials'?
I've configured my servlet context file with following beans

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="WEB-INF/messages" />       
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />       
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>
```

I'm able to use `<spring:message>` tag to display messages from my custom file . In the same file I've redefined all messages that are mapped to 'Bad Credentials' in spring-security-core.jar (messages.properties file) but they are not used. I still see 'Bad Credentials' message.
How can I override these spring messages?

Comment: maybe the spring properties file is loaded after yours? you could turn the log levels to debug and try to figure out

Comment: That means that it's not a feature, because it's platform dependent. The last thing I want to do is to mess with classpath. There definitely must be some mechanism for that.

Comment: Actually load order was the problem, but correct way to deal with it is to define these beans in right context file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that these beans should be defined in general application context and not in myservlet-servlet.xml file. Once I moved the definitions from servlet context it started to work as expected.

Answer (score -2):

Use correct property name.

Use basenames instead of basename